# How can I display text message if woocommerce quantity input is greater than stock quantity?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display a custom text message to notify customers that their selected input quantity (prior to clicking the "Add to Cart" button). This message will appear if the selected quantity is greater than the existing available stock quantity, right above the quantity selection within the individual product page. For example:

```
Existing Stock Quantity: 2
User Selects: >2
```

In such a scenario, I would like to tell the customer something like: "Your selected order quantity is greater than our existing stock. Please expect a delay of up to 2 weeks for our stock to be replenished."

I've tried to add the custom code into Code Snippets which looks something like that:

```
function display_order_quantity_exceeds_stock_quantity_text( $message, $product ) {

if( $product->woocommerce_quantity_input() > $product->get_stock_quantity()) {
    $message = "Your selected order quantity is greater than our existing stock. Please expect a delay of up to 2 weeks for our stock to be replenished.";
}
return $message;
```

}

Does anyone know how I can obtain the woocommerce_quantity_input and get this to work?

**Would prefer to have the solution just by adding a function into Code Snippets, rather than using Javascript (if possible).**

Answer (score 1):

I would do this through jQuery, so add this to your functions.php (the $src variable points to your JS file location in your theme folder):

```
function a3_enqueue_scripts() {
    if(is_singular( 'product' )){       
        $handle = 'a3_wooc_js';

        //path to your Javascript file
        $src = get_theme_file_uri( '/js/a3_wooc.js' );

        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, array( 'jquery' ), false, false);  
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'a3_enqueue_scripts' );
```

And something like this in the included JS file:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //the jQuery selector depends on your theme output for the quantity text box identifiers
        $('[name="quantity"]').on('change', function(e){
            var qty_box = $(this);
            var error_message = $('<div class="error_msg">Your selected order quantity is greater than our existing stock. Please expect a delay of up to 2 weeks for our stock to be replenished</div>');

            console.log(parseInt(qty_box.val()), parseInt(qty_box.attr('max')), qty_box.val() > parseInt(qty_box.attr('max')));

            if(parseInt(qty_box.val()) > parseInt(qty_box.attr('max'))) {
                // the action to take if the quantity exceeds max stock     
                if($('.quantity .error_msg').length < 1){
                    $('.quantity').prepend(error_message);                              
                }               
            }
            else {
                $('.quantity .error_msg').remove();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've tried your steps but it doesn't seem to work though. When I try to increase the quantity, no message is being displayed. Am I missing out something here?

Comment: In which file/folder in your theme did you put the jQuery code? Is your $src variable pointing to that path? Are you testing on the single-product page? Have you tried clearing the page cache, browser cache?

Comment: I had placed the jQuery within my theme/assets/js folder and changed the $src path accordingly, and it's referencing properly in the console. As for the php function, I've added in using the Code Snippets plugin instead of placing it within the functions.php file. Yes, I'm testing it on the single-product page, but it doesn't display any text as I increase the order quantity. Tried clearing browser and page cache but to no avail.

Comment: @steakoverflow: Any way to merge all the code into a single snippet to be added into functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this jQuery code in your theme's footer.php will trigger an alert when user enters a value more than stock

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function show_error($field, $mesg) {
    if ($field.prev('.error_msg').length) {
        $field.prev('.error_msg').html('<p>' + $mesg + '</p>');
    } else {
        jQuery('<div class="error_msg" style="color:#f00"><p>' + $mesg + '</p></div>').insertBefore($field);
    }

}

function remove_error($field) {
    if ($field.prev('.error_msg').length) {
        $field.prev('.error_msg').remove();
    }
}

jQuery(".quantity input[name=quantity]").on('change', function(e) {

    if (jQuery(this).val() > jQuery(this).attr("max")) {
        show_error(jQuery(this).parent(".quantity"), "Your selected order quantity is greater than our existing stock. Please expect a delay of up to 2 weeks for our stock to be replenished")
    } else {
        remove_error(jQuery(this).parent(".quantity"));
    }
})

</script>
```

You must have to enable Manage stock, and have set a stock number for this product to get it working.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled Managed stock and set a stock number for different product variations. It works, but it doesn't seem to be doing the calculations right. Every single time I increment the order quantity, the alert pop up appears. Also, I do not wish to have it alert the customer, but rather just displaying the message above the quantity selection div. Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating your code! However, the "jQuery(this).val() > jQuery(this).attr("max")" comparison doesn't seem to be working. As long as the input quantity reaches 2 and above, the error message seem to be displaying. Is there something that I am doing wrongly here?

Comment: I have modified my code to include parseInt, it was comparing quantities as strings.

Comment: @ZhanHao Please ensure you have provided the stock quantity value for the product https://imgur.com/a/MxHV2Ke

Comment: @steakoverflow I've tried your updated code but it still doesn't seem to compare correctly. I've checked the javascript console and it seems to not be able to recognize parseInt(qty_box.attr('max')) as an integer. I'm getting "2 NaN false, 3 NaN false, 4 NaN false" everytime I increment the order quantity by 1.

Comment: @jamsheerK Yes, I have set the stock quantity value for the product as per your screenshot, but it still doesn't seem to be making the right comparison...

Comment: If you could share the link, it would be helpful to identify the issue, also please try the solution suggested by @steakoverflow

Comment: @ZhanHao do you have variations on that product?

Comment: @ZhanHao, have you set the stock values on each variation? NaN value in your console.log means there's no max attribute (or the attribute is empty) on your quantity text box in your html output, and that means the stock quantity hasn't been setup.